# Big O of f(n) = N! + 2^N

Tags: big-o

I'm examining the function

```
f(n) = N! + 2^N
```

Supposedly, this is

```
O(N^N)
```

I'm not quite sure why this is, or how to prove this is true.

I would think that it is

```
O(N!)
```

Can you provide an explanation why Big O for

```
f(n) = N! + 2^N => O(N^N)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It really belongs on [cs.se]

Comment: because N! is BIG, really BIG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions , for further informations we have the CS corner as noted above

Comment: My mistake @MikeW. In the future, I will put my Big O questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed `O(N!)` and since `N!` is `O(N^N)` (because `N!` <= `N^N` for all N>0), anything in `O(N!)` is also in `O(N^N)`.

Comment: Is this considered a relatively tight bound? Is there a special relationship between N! and N^N I should consider in all my Big O problems?

Comment: @user2485710 No, it's <=. N^N is `N*N*...*N`. `N!` is `1*2*...*N`. In both cases you have the same number of terms and the terms in `N!` are all less than or equal to N while the terms in `N^N` are all exactly `N`. Therefore `N! <= N^N`. Also note that if N! were greater than `N^N` (by a non-constant factor), `N!` would not be `O(N^N)`, so the premise of the question would be false.

Comment: @Brandon Have a look at [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) which gives an asymptotic exact approximation for `N!`. Remove the factor of `sqrt(2pi)` and you have a tight big-O bound.